# Getting the key from a Deque of a HashMap

Tags: java, list, dictionary, data-structures

I have a deque that looks like this:

```
@Getter
private Deque<Map<int, String>> cars = new LinkedList<>();
```

I want to remove each car from the deque of the map using only the key. So something like this:

```
getCars().stream().forEach(car -> delete(car.keySet().iterator().next()));
```

Is there a better way to handle this, instead of having to use `interator().next()`?

Comment: What are the contents of each car's map? The question is a bit unclear, at least to me. Could you share some sample data and the result you'd like to get?

Comment: Each car can have an int value like 1,2,3,4 has sort of like an id. Then String is can be a color etc. Content really doesn't matter, as long as I can pinpoint a specific car from the map and delete it based on the int value I provide

Comment: So you want to pass an `int` value and delete all the cars that have that int as a key?

Comment: No. I want to remove all of the cars without having to pass an int. But instead, iterate through all the keys and remove each car from the deque. usually when its just a map, I can use keySet() and then remove all the cars from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method should do the trick:

```
int keyToDelete = 7; // Arbitrary number
cars.removeIf(m -> m.containsKey(keyToDelete));
```

**EDIT:**

In earlier Java versions the same functionality is also possible, although the syntax would be clunkier - you'll have to get an iterator of the list, and go over it, evaluating every item:

```
int keyToDelete = 7; // Arbitrary number
Iterator<Map<Integer, String>> iter = cars.iterator();

while(iter.hasNext()) {
    Map<Integer, String> map = iter.next();
    if (map.containsKey(keyToDelete)) {
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: can be used in lesser versiones than java 8?

Comment: @RafaelPalomino no, lambdas are Java 8 syntax. You could instead use the "clunkier" syntax of iterating over the list - see my edited answer.